# Is it normal for pipes under the hood to have cracks in them?

Tags: nissan, hood

On a Nissan March 2008, I noticed that the some pipes under the hood seem to have
cracks or openings in them. Is this normal?

[image: Pipe Cracks 1]

[image: Pipe Cracks 2]

Comment: I thought "March 2008" was a date, on first reading.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The top photo looks like it is the engine air intake duct before the filter.  While the holes shouldn’t be there, it won’t cause a problem, since the hole is before the air filter.  If it is after the filter, the hose needs replacing, since you will be letting unfiltered air in.  Add another photo showing the whole engine bay.

The second photo is just protection for the wiring harness.  The wrap is split like that from original, it is opened up and wrapped around the harness for protection against rubbing on the engine.  Nothing to worry about.

Comment: I'd say the first one is also a sign that something might be placed a bit wrong, it looks like chafing damage. Vibrating against the hood maybe?

Comment: @StianYttervik Yes, I agree.  The big mark to the left of the holes looks like it could be damage too.  It almost looks like it has melted.

Comment: It should be noted that if the intake duct were cracked post-air filter, the CEL would likely be on and the vehicle would idle rough or stall at idle, due to the MAF reading an airflow value that is incorrect. This would probably result in running lean and cause additional wear on spark plugs, among other things (cat?)

Comment: @BrydonGibson It depends on the engine, not all engines have MAF sensors.

Comment: The air intake looks like it could have been reinstalled at a slightly wrong angle (the elbow looks like it has a round fitting that doesn't seem to be keyed). I'd bet that it could be rotated so that it sits a few mm lower in the engine bay and that would prevent it from rubbing on the hood. It's too late to save this part, but it would prevent further damage as well as further damage to the hood's heat/vibration shielding pad.